# Troubleshoot SSL/TLS handshake in Google Chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, https, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

I would like to inspect the SSL/TLS handshake in Google Chrome (or Chromium) browser.

I'm looking for output similar to what you'd see using commands like these from other HTTPS clients (just examples):

```
➜  ~  curl -k -v https://foo.com:443 --tlsv1
```

or

```
➜  ~  openssl s_client -debug -connect foo.com:443 -tls1
```

I've searched a bit, and it doesn't look like native tools (ie via inspect element) nor plugins have this level of visibility.

Comment: I would suggest trying a man-in-the-middle SSL proxy using Fiddler or Charles. I've had decent luck with those.

Comment: Thanks.  Unfortunately, Fiddler and Charles don't provide the detailed logging that a client can provide.

Comment: it would have been nice if Chrome Inspector would allow you to copy and paste the entire curl command WITH the certificate passed. I'm assuming it doesn't. I couldn't get it working.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may use Wireshark(https://www.wireshark.org/) to capture the network packets, and use the

```
Menu->Statistics->Flow Graph
```

to view the network sequence as below. Below diagram illustrates the TCP flow visiting stackoverflow.com. Meanwhile, you can click on the arrows in the diagram to inspect down to ethernet frame level, including TCP/IP/Ethernet packets.

[image: TCP flow visiting stackoverflow.com]

Answer (score 3):

I found chrome://net-export very useful for tracing down communication issues like SSL handshake in Chrome Browser.

Unfortunately needs a chrome plugin for better visualization of the resulting JSON file.

Hope this helps